# Would like to store system settings in core data

Tags: core-data, swiftui

Using SwiftUI

I have created a CoreData Entity called SystemSettings and would like to use the information stored in it for calculating results in different functions on different views without using ForEach.  SystemSettings will always have only one object (Record) stored from preloaded database. Is there a way I can use @FetchRequest and pull out the only object and its attributes out, as a var.... ?

Thank you

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct NewComponent: View {
    
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: SystemSettings.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var settings: FetchedResults<SystemSettings>
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
 
    var calculator = Calculator()

    // USER DATA TEXT FIELDS
    @State var parameterOne = "12.5"
    @State var parameterTwo = "2.5"
    @State var calculationResult = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Form {
               
                
                Section (header: Text("Parameters").font(.headline).bold().italic()) {
                    HStack {
                        Text ("Length")
                            .font(.headline)
                        Spacer()
                        TextField ("m", text: $parameterOne).modifier(ClearButton(text: $parameterOne))
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text ("Width")
                            .font(.headline)
                        Spacer()
                        TextField ("m", text: $parameterTwo).modifier(ClearButton(text: $parameterTwo))
                            
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                            .font(.headline)
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
            Section(header:
                Text("\(self.calculationResult)").bold().italic().padding(.top)
                
            ) {
                
                Button(action: {
                
                    self.calculationResult = self.result()
                    
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "x.squareroot")
                        Text("Calculate!")
                        Spacer()
                    }.font(.headline).foregroundColor(Color.green)
                        .padding(.bottom, 40.0).padding(.top, 20.0)
                }
            }
            
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Component Calculator"))
            .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged{_ in UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)})
            .modifier(KeyboardObserving())
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                
                let newEstimatedComponent = EstimatedComponents(context: self.moc)
                newEstimatedComponent.name = "New Component"
                newEstimatedComponent.price = self.priceToDisplay()

                try? self.moc.save()
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                
        }){Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle").font(.system(size: 30))})
    }
    

    func result () -> String {
        
        let result = componentCost()

        return (String(format: "%.2f",(result)) + " €")
    }
    
    func priceToDisplay() -> Double {
        
        return componentCost() 
    }
    
    func componentCost () -> Double {
            
return calculator (componentWidth: Double(parameterOne), componentHight: Double(parameterTwo), componentPrice: settings!.componentM2Price )

}

/*settings!componentM2Price not working of course, so I need to get the first and the only object from SystemSettings Entity in a way that I can use it in func componentCost()...*/
```

THANKS AGAIN...

Comment: Yes it would be exactly the same as any other fetch request that fetches all elements. Considering you will have only one record maybe you should use UserDefaults instead?

Comment: Appreciate the comment, but how do I use fetchedResults in a non view environment? Class with functions that I use in different views elsewhere in the app?  I want to use core data, later on it will be connected to cloudKit and backup options... Thanks

Comment: Just use it a normal fetch request the way it was done before SwiftUI, so basically see any Core Data tutorial more than a year old. Given you only will have one instance maybe you should have a single class for accessing and updating it

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
@EnvironmentObject var settings: ModifySystemSettings
let systemSettings: SystemSettings
```

You can find more information here:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views